# Place second mat toolbar under main mat toolbar?

Tags: html, css, angular

I am trying to place a secondary mat toolbar under the main mat tool bar but its too large

I want it to look like this. The thin gray toolbar highlighted in red. Instead its a large toolbar underneath that. Also I need the words "Custom Toolbar 2" to be text center
[image]

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary" class="mat-elevation-z24 topo" 
    [style.margin-bottom]="'24px'">
  <mat-toolbar-row>
    <span>Custom Toolbar 1</span>
  </mat-toolbar-row>
</mat-toolbar>

<mat-toolbar>
  <mat-toolbar-row>
    <span>Custom Toolbar 2</span>
  </mat-toolbar-row>
</mat-toolbar>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use some css styling

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary" class="mat-elevation-z24 topo">
  <span>Custom Toolbar 1</span>
</mat-toolbar>

<mat-toolbar style="height: 24px; background-color: #ccc; justify-content: center">
  <span>Custom Toolbar 2</span>
</mat-toolbar>
```

I have used inline styling for simplicity. You may however use a css class to define the same.

Also, suggest to remove the `mat-elevation-z24` class which casts a 24px shadow

Answer (score 0):

You could use rows for this.

```html
<mat-toolbar color="primary">
  <mat-toolbar-row>
    <span>Custom toolbar #1</span>
    <a routerLink="/link1" mat-button>link#1</a>
  </mat-toolbar-row>
  <mat-toolbar-row class="mat-toolbar">
    <span>Custom toolbar #2</span>
    <a routerLink="/link1" mat-button>link#2</a>
  </mat-toolbar-row>
</mat-toolbar>
```

[image]